# Дано предложение. Удалить из каждого слова все повторяющиеся буквы

Tags: c, строки

Дано предложение. Удалить из каждого слова все повторяющиеся
буквы, т.е. в каждом слове должны остаться только различные
буквы.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <Windows.h> 
int main()
{
    char str[80];
        SetConsoleCP(1251);//включить кодировку Win1251 при вводе с консоли 
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);//включить кодировку Win1251 при выводе на консоли 

        int i = 0, j, k, z, ks, ns = 0;
        printf("Введите предложение:\n");
        gets_s(str);

        while (str[i] != '\0')//пока не конец строки выполняется цикл 
        {
            while (str[i] == ' ')//пока встречается пробел перебираем символы 
                i++;
            ns = i;//начало слова 
            while ((str[i] != ' ') || (str[i] != '\0'))//пока не встретится пробел или конец строки перебираем символы 
                i++;
            ks = i - 1;//конец слова 
            for (j = ns; j < ks; j++)
                for (k = j + 1; k <= ks; k++)
                    if (str[j] == str[k])//нужно осуществить копирование хвоста, удалить из k 
                        for (z = k; z <= ks; z++)
                        {
                            if (str[z] != str[j])
                                str[z] = str[z++];
                            if (str[z] == str[j])
                                str[z] = str[z + 1];
                        }
        }
    puts("Новое предложение:\n");
    puts(str);
    getchar(); getchar();
}
```

Не получается правильно "удалить" символы. В лучшем случае уходит одна буква из первого слова. Данный код не работает на строке

Comment: Это как это? Как уже правильно было замечено, `gets_s` требует два параметра. Код не компилируем в принципе. Откуда взялись сказки про "уходит одна буква из первого слова"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, как у вас компилируется... вы используете `gets_s`, но это функция с двумя параметрами...

По вашему коду... Можно, я предложу свой? Итак, мы делим строку на слова при помощи `strtok`, а затем просто обрабатываем и выводим каждое слово.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

char* handleWord(char* w)
{
    for(char *b = w; *b; ++b)
        for(char *e = b+1; *e; ++e)
            while (*e == *b)
                memmove(e,e+1,strlen(e+1)+1);
    return w;
}

int main()
{
    char str[80];
    SetConsoleCP(1251);//включить кодировку Win1251 при вводе с консоли
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);//включить кодировку Win1251 при выводе на консоли

    printf("Введите предложение:\n");
    gets_s(str, 80);
    for(char * w = strtok(str," "); w; w = strtok(NULL," "))
        printf("%s ",handleWord(w));
    puts("");
    getchar();
}
```

Так мы работаем в пределах слова, нам не нужно двигать всю строку при удалении дублей.

**Update**
Вот, не портим строку, ничего не двигаем... Теперь все довольны?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

bool isIn(const char * b, const char * c)
{
    for(;b!=c;++b)
        if (*b == *c) return true;
    return false;
}

void outWord(const char * b, const char * e)
{
    for(const char * c = b; c != e; ++c)
        if (!isIn(b,c)) putchar(*c);
}

int main()
{
    char str[80];
    SetConsoleCP(1251);//включить кодировку Win1251 при вводе с консоли
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);//включить кодировку Win1251 при выводе на консоли

    printf("Введите предложение:\n");
    gets_s(str, 80);
    for(const char *b = str, *e = str; *b ; b = e)
    {
        if (*b == ' ')
        {
            putchar(' ');
            while(*b && *b == ' ') ++b;
        }
        e = b;
        while(*e && *e != ' ') ++e;
        outWord(b,e);
    }
    puts("");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Буква это любой символ? (кстати, `strtok()` необратимо колечит исходную строку, может стоит упомянуть в ответе?)

Comment: @avp Поскольку у автора вопроса строка тоже калечится, я не стал акцентировать на этом внимание

Comment: У автора она каличится по его неумению. Ему просто нужно  копировать все, исключая "дубликаты в пределах слова" (а не двигать хвост) по индексу общему для всей строки и тогда все  получится.

Comment: @avp Так устраивает?

Comment: Класс, надеюсь, автору тоже понравится.

Answer (score 3):

Ну или вот вариант удаления без постоянных перемещений остатков слова:

```
static char *remove_dups( char *word )
{
    if( word && *word ) {
        size_t idx = 1;
        char *copy = word;
        for( char *ptr = word + 1; *ptr; ptr++ ) {
            if( *ptr != copy[idx-1] ) {
                copy[idx++] = *ptr;
            }
        }
        word[idx] = 0;
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: А вы **все** дубли **букв** (кстати, проверку на **букву** вообще не вижу) удаляете (или только те, что подряд идут)?

Comment: @avp, подряд. Но из задания не очень понятно так нужно или нет. И с буквами тоже путаница: то буквы, то "символы", в исходногм коде разницы нет :) P.S. Если нужно все повторы, а не только подряд идущие, то можно вообще завести массив со счётчиками - алфавит позволяет.